# How to sendinput to other window without making it active?

Tags: c#, winapi, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I have googled so many side that about sendinput to an non-active window.
However, all of the method I found will make the target windows get focus. Here is an example:

```
IntPtr NotepadHandle = FindWindow("Notepad", "Untitled - Notepad");
uint noteid = GetWindowThreadProcessId(NotepadHandle, IntPtr.Zero);
uint selfid = GetCurrentThreadId();
bool attach = AttachThreadInput(selfid, noteid, true);
SetFocus(NotepadHandle);
//sendInput"a"=================================================
INPUT Input = new INPUT();
Input.type = 1; //keyboard_input
Input.ki.wVk = 65; //a
Input.ki.dwFlags = 0;
SendInput(1, ref Input, Marshal.SizeOf(Input));

Input = new INPUT();
Input.type = 1;
Input.ki.wVk = 65;
Input.ki.dwFlags = 2;//key_up
SendInput(1, ref Input, Marshal.SizeOf(Input));
//sendInput"a"=================================================
bool cutattach = AttachThreadInput(selfid, noteid, false);
```

It can send an "a" to non-active Notepad but what I want is keeping the Notepad non-force or even minimized.

Is there anyway to do that? Thank you!

---

The reason why I am asking this is I found an old app called "[WindClick](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4VasldGvA7QdEtGblhIRGtnZFU)" which can do what I want. "WindClick" can keep clicking other windows while I am using the PC.
But it cannot save config so I am trying to make a similar app.
How can I make an app like that?

Comment: I think most of the windows input model is based on the assumption that only the active window is receiving input. Whilst you *may* get lucky trying to force input to non-active windows, how that other application will react (especially if it's not one that you control (in terms of being a software author of it)) is probably not guaranteed.

Comment: Hi Damien_The_Unbeliever, The reason why I am asking this is I found an old app called "WindClick" which can do what I want. "WindClick" can keep clicking other windows while I am using the PC. But it cannot save config so I am trying to make a similar app. How can I make an app like that?
Download: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4VasldGvA7QdEtGblhIRGtnZFU

Comment: Have you considered automation. Why did you reject it. Why do so many people view faking input as the answer.

Comment: [`AttachThreadInput` is probably more dangerous than you think.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130619-00/?p=4043)

Comment: benefited by you guys
Thank you!
I will try to do it by UI auto